# Android Studio Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library is missing

Tags: android

I use Android Studio. I want try GCM like this tutorial. My Android SDK tools 22.6.

But I cant see Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library.
I install new SDK but again I cant see.

My sdk image.[image]

Please Help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's now part of the play services. I guess you need to find a new tutorial.

Comment: Aaa I understand now. Thank you @rekire. Do know new tutorial for GCM :)

Comment: A good place to start is the official documentation http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html